# Issue after removing computer from Active Directory domain

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, active-directory

I need some hints about an issue I faced it's a bit irritated.

Let me explain the whole scenario and maybe you have some ideas behind it.

One of the computers has Windows 10 LTSC 2019 x64 and it's timezone was +8 Pasific. I decided to change it to +3 with using;

- domain user account (as logging into the computer with it) (which is local administrator in that computer)
- local admin account (as logging into the computer with it)
- domain admin account (as logging into the computer with it)

but I couldn't change it due some security reasons. Then I thought that maybe it's about some kind of GPO settings and decided to disjoin the computer from the Active Directory temporarily and rejoin it later.
When it was in Workgroup, I restarted it. Then, the computer began to install Windows Updates. I waited about 20-25 minutes to finish it. After restart, there was only the domain user account which has standard user right on the screen.

1- I don't see any users down left corner to switch

2- I don't see Other User option down left corner

3- The screen doesn't allow me to specify user account because only one option there.

4- I remember this standard domain user account's password pretty well and the damn computer doesn't remember it and it doesn't allow me to log in.

5- I installed Windows 10 and setup this computer 1 day ago without any error.

I don't have any clue how this is happened and what can be the reasons of it.

Any ideas?

Thanks..

Comment: Your computer is not in the domain anymore, so you need to use the password that was used when setting up the pc, which can also be an empty password.

Comment: LTSC requires a KMS so you will want to eventually join it back to the domain.  Sounds like you should simply reinstall Windows, since it’s only been a day, and you don’t have the required access.  It’s not clear the reason you attempted to change the timezone outside of the domain server.

Comment: All passwords I know didn't work, including empty one. The problem is about not able to selecting local user account even if I can use them when the computer is in domain. There is only one thing I have in mind which may cause it, which is that I had configured only some specific domain user accounts as a local admins, excluding the current user and domain admins. Maybe excluding domain admins from local administrators built-in group may effect it but I don't have a valid reason for it.

Comment: Have you enabled the built-in Administrator and tried logging into that account?

Comment: It was in default state but I had another local admin account in place. So, even if I solve the issue later, I need to identify the root cause of it.